# ffmpegでs3上のファイルにアクセスしようとすると”Protocol not found"と言われる

Tags: ffmpeg, amazon-s3, https

現在、表題の問題に悩まされております。

PCローカル上の動画にターミナルよりffmpegで以下のコードを実行するときちんと成功し、ファイルが作られます。

```
% ffmpeg -i /Users/MacBookProMGX82JA/Desktop/mov_h264_aac.mov -vf trim=0:5 \
/Users/MacBookProMGX82JA/Desktop/mov_h264_aac_2.mov
```

しかし、ファイル名だけをS3上に存在するファイルに置き換えた所、

```
% ffmpeg -i https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/nigari/uploads/article/video/1/mov_h264_aac.mov -vf trim=0:5 \
/Users/MacBookProMGX82JA/Desktop/mov_h264_aac_2.mov
https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/nidomi/uploads/article/video/1/mov_h264_aac.mov: \
Protocol not found
```

というエラーになります。

S3上のファイルは鍵がかかっているわけではなく、リンクを踏めばDLできます。
curlコマンドでは普通にダウンロードできます。

```
% curl -O ttps://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/nigari/uploads/article/video/1/mov_h264_aac.mov                            (git)-[cutmovie]
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2494k  100 2494k    0     0  2828k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2827k
^_^  [MacBookProMGX82JA@mgx82ja] ~/rails_projects/nigari
```

しかしffmpegコマンドではProtocol not foundエラーとなるのです。

本家を含めかなり考えましたがこのメッセージだけでは解決することはできませんでした。
何が原因なのか分かりますでしょうか？ここまで読んでいただきありがとうございます。

---

（1/23追記）
皆さまありがとうございます、順を追って説明いたします
まず、私はffmpegについてよく理解しておらず、homebrewで入れたものを特に問題を感じずそのまま使っていました。
質問時点でのversionですが

```
% ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 14 2014 07:21:22 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-   pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
```

でした。gnu-tlsライブラリは含まれていないようです。
その後、gnu-tlsライブラリを含め、ソースからmakeしました。

```
% ./ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 23 2015 09:43:11 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/ffmpeg_gnutls/sw -- libdir=/Volumes/ffmpeg_gnutls/sw/lib --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-pthreads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-shared --enable-static --arch=x86_64
libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

このffmpegにより、S3上のファイルが確かに変換されました。
自分では決して分からないことでした、本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: `ffmpeg --version` の結果をぜひ上げてください。

Comment: GnuTLS は OpenSSL 互換です。で、 Homebrew だと `$ brew install ffmpeg --with-openssl` でOpenSSL が使えます。

Comment: 素晴らしい情報ありがとうございます！Homebrewでもできたのですね、互換についても知りませんでした。

Comment: `brew info ffmpeg` すると、インストールオプションのリストが出ます。個人的なオススメは `--with-openssl` と `--with-rtmpdump` ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnu-tlsライブラリ含めるオプションを付けずにビルドしたffmpegを使っているのではないですか？
ffmpeg --versionの結果ををみるとわかりますよ。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/riocampos+tech/20130731/p1

Comment: 引用元の著者です。 FFmpeg ビルドに GnuTLS か OpenSSL が含まれていないかもしれませんね。いずれにせよ、ローカルと HTTP/HTTPS とでは大きく違うと思います。